# The expression contains an invalid string constant: '

Tags: string, textbox, constants

this code is in Textbox Change event.

dds.Tables["IncomeGenerator"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "' Income LIKE '*" + txtSearch.Text + "*' OR Expenses LIKE '*" + txtSearch.Text + "*' OR Date LIKE '*" + txtSearch.Text + "*' OR Balance LIKE '*" + txtSearch.Text + "*' OR Description LIKE '*" + txtSearch.Text +  "*'";

when i run it, it gives a error saying  " The expression contains an invalid string constant: '. "

can someone help me.

my Income, Expenses and Balance is Data Type Float and Date is Datetime. i hope it may help. can someone guide me with the mistake and help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure, but sometimes when I copy code from a web page or word processor, I inadvertently include a "book quote" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs) that screws things up.

It looks like there may be some in the sample you posted. Try making sure all the quotes are the straight-up-and-down quotes, and not the begin-end "book quotes".